# Capybara attach_file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, automated-tests, capybara

I have a feature test in my application where I test uploading a file. So I have something like this:

```
attach_file :input_id, Rails.root + "spec/fixtures/sample.jpg"
click_button "Upload"
```

My "expects" are always failing, I add a binding.pry to my controller to check why. It turns out the what is being passed to the input file is a string.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Any suggestions on how to go about the problem? Been stuck at this problem for 2 days now.

---

EDIT

Forgot to mention, the input file is a multiple type

```
f.attachment_field :input_field, multiple: true
```

Comment: What library are you using that provides the #attachment_field method? If refile - do you happen to be using direct or presigned modes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked a question in the comment about whether #attachment_field is from refile and you're using direct or presigned mode. To save time if your answers to that are yes:

Refile when using direct or presigned mode doesn't upload the file with the form, rather it submits the file using ajax to its own sinatra app, S3, etc (dependent on the backend used) and then submits the id of the file upload in the hidden field added to the form.  In that case you would expect that to be a string.  You can read more about it https://github.com/refile/refile#4-rails-helpers and https://github.com/refile/refile#5-javascript-library

Comment: Oh that's why! THANKS! I have been stuck with writing the test for 3 days now. Now, do you have any example on how to test refile with attach_file of capybara? do I have to use the wait function to wait for the ajax of refile?

Comment: If you look at the refile.js in the refile project, by default it adds a class 'uploading' to the file input, so you could do something like `expect(page).to have_no_css('input.uploading') ` to have capybara wait until the upload is complete -- or if you're doing anything with the custom events refile fires you could wait for those changes

Comment: Also if you look at the tests in the refile project, they use Capybaras attach_file so you should get plenty of examples there

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
attach_file('Image', "spec/files/images/yourtestimg.jpg")
```

Create those folders in the path, obviously. Sorry, I'd rather over explain than not. `yourtestimg.jpg` is referring to an actual image i put in that folder.

A quick side note, the above is the correct way to do it, however one time I ran into an fail because it didn't recognise 'Image'. In that case, right click and inspect element of the upload button and see what the field has been named. In the fail I am talking about the field was name 'post_image', likewise the caption field was named 'post_caption'. Once I swapped Image for 'post_image' it passed fine.

Justin

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm not actually encountering any problem in "javascript selecting" or the file exist in capybara. But when the form has uploaded the input file value is actually a string instead of an object. If you need a sample hash, I'll gladly post it here.